# What is this CRC32 algorithm (written in C), and how can it be written in Java or Python?

Tags: c, ghidra, python, java, crc

I've been trying to convert this CRC32 algorithm to Java or Python, but I haven't been successful, I believe it's because I'm not familiar enough with c.

Note that I believe `DAT_804818d0` is the seed, which I still haven't found.

This was my naive attempt at converting the below code to Java (I suspect I've made numerous mistakes): https://pastebin.com/6XnxqaBp

```
uint zz_801744d0_(byte *param_1,int param_2)

{
  byte *pbVar1;
  byte *pbVar2;
  byte *pbVar3;
  byte *pbVar4;
  byte *pbVar5;
  byte *pbVar6;
  byte bVar7;
  bool bVar8;
  int iVar9;
  int iVar10;
  uint uVar11;
  uint uVar12;
  
  uVar11 = DAT_80481ad0;

  //The code in this if statement appears to handle the first 4 bytes in a special manner
  if (3 < param_2) {
    pbVar1 = param_1 + 1;
    param_2 = param_2 + -4;
    pbVar2 = param_1 + 2;
    bVar7 = *param_1;
    pbVar3 = param_1 + 3;
    param_1 = param_1 + 4;
    uVar11 = ~((uint)bVar7 << 0x18 | (uint)*pbVar1 << 0x10 | (uint)*pbVar2 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar3);
  }

  iVar10 = 0;
  if (0 < param_2) { //If the data was 4 bytes in size or less, we just return ~uVar11
    if (8 < param_2) { //If the data was 12 bytes or more, the rest are handled in chunks of 8 bytes
      bVar8 = false;
      if ((-1 < param_2) && (param_2 < 0x7fffffff)) {
        bVar8 = true;
      }
      if ((bVar8) && (uVar12 = param_2 - 1U >> 3, 0 < param_2 + -8)) {
        do {
          iVar10 = iVar10 + 8;
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*param_1) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          pbVar1 = param_1 + 2;
          pbVar2 = param_1 + 3;
          pbVar3 = param_1 + 4;
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)param_1[1]) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          pbVar4 = param_1 + 5;
          pbVar5 = param_1 + 6;
          pbVar6 = param_1 + 7;
          param_1 = param_1 + 8;
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar1) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar2) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar3) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar4) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar5) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)*pbVar6) ^
                   *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
          uVar12 = uVar12 - 1;
        } while (uVar12 != 0);
      }
    }
    iVar9 = param_2 - iVar10;
    if (iVar10 < param_2) { //Any remaining bytes are handled one at a time.
      do {
        bVar7 = *param_1;
        param_1 = param_1 + 1;
        uVar11 = (uVar11 << 8 | (uint)bVar7) ^ *(uint *)(&DAT_804818d0 + (uVar11 >> 0x16 & 0x3fc));
        iVar9 = iVar9 + -1;
      } while (iVar9 != 0);
    }
  }
  return ~uVar11;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use it in Java/Python or do you really need a native implementation? because often it is easier to include the executable/library the function is implemented in into a a custom library that has an interface to Java or Python so you can simple use the original implementation.

Comment: I believe I need a non-native implementation. The binary was compiled for Wii architecture. I'm not aware of anything (other than emulation) which allows a PC to run portions of a Wii game binary.